# My laptop (Acer Aspire) doesn't want to start

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure

I have an Acer Aspire 5520G and recently I had a big problem with it. A couple of days ago I was watching a video on the internet and my laptop froze. I had to shut it down after waiting a couple of minutes and when I wanted to restart it, it acted normally for 2 seconds then it restarts automatically over and over again. I can only shut it down by unplugging it. Nothing appears on screen. I think that it is a hardware problem. If you need further information please leave comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this a a common problem with this particular model of laptop.  If it is still under warranty, (unlikely given its age) contact Acer for assistance.

[Apparently some people have had success correcting the problem using a heat gun.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XykI-u9mSOY)  That might sound weird, but it's just a roundabout way of [reflowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflow_soldering) the northbridge, which was poorly soldered to the motherboard and causes this problem.  Unfortunately many people report this "solution" to be temporary, and I wouldn't recommend messing with it.

Personally, I would just buy a new laptop.  You could replace the motherboard, but it will probably be cheaper and easier to get a new one instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will try it and let you know if it works!

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and it worked! I used a hair dryer because it was the only thing I had but it worked. Thanks!